# How to load block by ajax in background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-templates

I have tree structure in my template which created by [Nestable2](https://github.com/RamonSmit/Nestable2) plugin. I render tree structure with next html which you can see below. It works but render some heavy pages with a lot of data too slow.

By default when user open the page tree is collapse. I show top level nodes first and then check if they have descendants. You can see it in html. The main load to database happens when I check all descendants of the node in this line: `node.get_children`.

**Question**: Is it possible to load this part `{% if node.get_children %} *** {% endif %}` by ajax in background when page is opened? I want to know your ideas, I would be grateful for examples. My aim is to speed up page loading.

**main.html**:

```
<ol class="dd-list">
{% for node in nodes %}
    {% include "tree_template.html" %}
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

**tree_template.html**:

```
<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="{{node.id}}">
    <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle"></div>
    <div class="dd-content dd3-content">***</div>

    {% if node.get_children %}
    <ol class="dd-list">
        {% for child in node.get_children %}
            {% with node=child template_name="tree_template.html" %}
                {% include template_name %}
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    {% endif %}
</li>
```

Comment: Are your templates rendered on the server?

Comment: Hello @Sergiu :) Well, not certainly in that way but close. I create `nodes` (top level nodes) in view and send them to django template where then I render it by built-in template tag `for`. After that I check every node for availability of сhildren. `get_children` method is set in `models.py` file. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If I correctly understand, you want to load a specific part of an html page on demand?

Comment: In my case it's not only one specific part. They can be several such specific parts cause every node may have children. I want to load this several parts in background mode when page is opened.

Comment: Then I believe you should have a representation of the DOM (a virtual DOM) on your server, so then you could query from it specific parts and return it to the client.

Comment: I don't have DOM in server. I thought about your last idea about loading special part (children) when user expand the node. Problem here is that I use serialize method (http://https://github.com/RamonSmit/Nestable2#methods) and this method create JSON by DOM of the tree. If DOM wouldn't be full JSON will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Template tags are rendered by the server when an url is called so no you can't.

What you can do is using [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) in your ajax controller:

```
def ajax_view(request, node):
    data = dict()
    for child in node.get_children():
       data[child] = render_to_string(
           'tree_template.html',
           {'node': child}
       )
    return JSONResponse(data)
```

Then with a bit of javascript add them to your page.

Comment: Hello! :) I am little bit confused. When and how I need to trigger this function?

Comment: You said you want to use ajax right ? This function is a django view just call its url.

Comment: It seems to me in this code don't considered a recursive nesting of nodes or I'm wrong? In my case maximum depth of the tree is 6. Also I need to change template?

Answer (score 0):

You could also think about using JSRender (https://www.jsviews.com/) to get data with AJAX after the page has loaded and then generate content dynamically using JSRender Templates.

Comment: Hello! :) Thank you for this link. I never heard about this plugin. Can you show me some example please based on my case.

Comment: Basically you have to do the following:1) convert your "tree_template.html" into a JSRender Template which is embedded with script tags in your HTML Code (examples on jsview.com). 2) When the page has loaded, perform a AJAX request in JavaScript to the backend to load the dynamic data. The backend must return the data as JSON, then it can be dynamically inserted in your HTML by calling the JSRender template.

[https://www.jsviews.com/#jsrplaying]